# How to imshow 2 different sources within same window in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'd like to have a picture-in-picture (PIP) effect, by showing 2 different image sources within a single OpenCV window. Image 1 has different dimensions as image 2, for example:

[image]

I can show 2 sources on separate windows by running 2 cv2.imshow(), but I'd like both sources in the same window.

I've tried doing PIP with cv2.add() as well as cv2.addWeighted() but it seems to be unable to handle the different dimensions.

Is this possible with OpenCV?

Comment: Easy manual way: just replace those pixels of the bigger image with the smaller one (need to calculate the dimension-sizes too). Maybe you did try it with add, but it's not an addition, it's a replacement. And to get help from all the opencv-users here, show some code, including your failed attempts.

Comment: Don't add, copy the each into an appropriately sized ROI of the rendering canvas.

Comment: thanks, how would I position it on the original (larger) image though?

Comment: If grayscale the bigger on has dimensions (N,M), the smaller one (n,m). Interpret it as a matrix. Then it's probably (top-right) [0:n, M-m:] = smaller-img (i'm assuming numpy-like slicing works). But check opencv's docs how those pixels are ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @sascha and @dan masek for the tips. As suggested a simple copy solves the issue as below:

```
# large image is 'frame'
# smale image is 'img'

frame[0:128, 872:1000] = img  # copy img onto upper left frame
cv2.imshow('screen', frame)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

[image]